# QGIS - omit attributes from output

Tags: qgis

Is there any simple way of excluding layer attributes from a QGIS tool output?

If I right-click --> Export, I get all layer attributes in the export, including those that are "Hidden" in the Attribute Form or Attribute table.
I can delete them from the output afterwards, but it can take some time (eg address data with 2.6 million records and only 3 or 4 of 85 data fields required).

It's the same with Dissolve results - the fields not selected to dissolve by are still present, but are worse than useless, because they have some random value in (presumably the from the first record encountered).

Ideally, it would be simple enough to give to those of my users who aren't up to writing SQL queries.

It was easy in ArcMap - get a list of field tickboxes with select all and unselect all buttons below, and anything unticked was omitted.

Solved:
I've been exporting by right-click --> Export --> Save features as, when I should be using Layer --> Save As

Comment: When you export in QGIS you get a list of the fields with tickboxes in the export dialogue (I think there is a fields section), is this what you mean?

Answer (score 6):

For outputs of processing tools that do not have a native option for this: **No**.

But you could run "Refactor Fields" processing tool on the output to remove, keep, rearrange or modify the fields as well as its content:

[image]

This tool also allows the usage of other layers as templates.

Also you can choose the fields to keep or remove when you export your layer as file:

[image]

Comment: I thought there should be something simple somewhere. I've been exporting by right-click --> Export --> Save features as

Answer (score 4):

I think The GUI of refactor fields is difficult when dealing with many fields and you just want to delete some fields, but I agree, it is the tool to use.

In that case you can create a little python script in which you can list the fields to delete (or keep if you modify the code) then the code will create the field mapping for refactor fields:

```
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('ak_riks')[0] #Change
fields_to_delete = ['KOMMUNNAMN','KATEGORI'] #Change

fm = [{'expression':f.name(), 'length':f.length(), 'name':f.name(), 
     'precision':f.precision(), 'type':f.type()} for f in lyr.fields() 
     if f.name() not in fields_to_delete]
     
processing.runAndLoadResults("native:refactorfields", {'INPUT':lyr,
                                'FIELDS_MAPPING':fm,
                                'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

[image]